# Problem with PHP Syntax

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get a link together using 2 variables but the output is the link and title but no html / clickable link appearing.

I'm getting something link this:

http://www.mydomain.com/post1/post_title_here

Here is the code:

```
echo '<a href="'.the_permalink().'">'.the_title().'</a>';
```

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

UPDATE:

Here's the whole block of code:

```
<div id="MyBlock1">
        <?php
            $query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5');

             while( $query ->have_posts() ) : $query ->the_post();
                 echo '<li>';
                 echo '<a href="'.the_permalink().'">'.the_title().'</a>';
                 echo '</li>';
             endwhile;

            wp_reset_postdata();

        ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Code looks fine to me. What is getting rendered? What is the return value of `the_permalink()`?

Comment: paste the code from the permalink function so we know what it returns

Comment: the_permalink() contains the link. eg: http://www.mydomain.com/post1/

Comment: As a general rule, if a function in Wordpress generates output of some sort, then `the_function()` sends the output directly to the client, while `get_the_function()` returns its output instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the wordpress functions `the_permalink()` and `the_title()` display the respective outcomes already they need not be echoed. If you want functions that return the values, you have to use `get_permalink()` and `get_the_title()` instead.

So either do:

```
<div id="MyBlock1">
    <?php
        $query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5');
        while( $query ->have_posts() ) : $query ->the_post();
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
            echo '</li>';
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
   ?>
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="MyBlock1">
    <?php
        $query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5');
        while( $query ->have_posts() ) : $query ->the_post();
            echo '<li><a href="';
            the_permalink();
            echo '">';
            the_title();
            echo '</a></li>';
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
   ?>
</div>
```

Both will work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a checklist for debugging:

1.) Is `the_title()` returning an empty string?  (You can check by looking at the html source)

2.) Are you echoing this inside of the body tag?

3.) Is this being echoed in a hidden html element?

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<a href="'.the_permalink().'">'.the_title().'</a>';
```

In this sort of situation, you'll want to use [`get_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) instead of `the_permalink` and [`get_the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_title) instead of `the_title`.

```
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
```

WordPress `the_*` functions do a direct `echo` call, whereas the `get_*` functions return a value that you can use for further processing, like the concatenation you're doing.

(also note the inconsistent naming conventions - this can be a pain)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the corresponding get_* versions:

```
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
```

See the [codex reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference) for more

Comment: It's actually `get_the_title`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to absolutely make sure that `.the_title().` is definately bieng set a value. If it isn't, then there will be no displayed HTML as there is no text for the anchor tag. Just a thought (i've done it many times, try `print_f();` ing the the_title(). Hope it helped.

Comment: Both variable are returning values.